# How to randomly render react components from firebase

Tags: reactjs, function, return, rendering

I am working on a project and trying to randomly show the components w/ data from firebase on the home page.

How can I recode this so that products are randomly generated?

Thanks in advance!

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './Product.css'

function Product(props) {
    console.log(props);
    return (
        <div className="Product">
            <div className="Product-description">
                <span className="Product-title">{props.title}</span>
                <span className="Product-price">${props.price}</span>
                <span className="Product-rating">
                    <p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p>
                </span>
            </div>
            <img src={props.image} />
            <button>Add to Cart</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Product
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create random number with;

```
const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * productCount);
```

And then, you can send as a prop and filter your randomly selected product by using this random number as index.